Using the decompiler in VS Code
I have a created project that I have been working with for a long time through VS 22. I also provided links to third-party libraries in order to work with them and view their classes and methods. This function works very conveniently in VS 22, but now I want to try using VS Code and I have some difficulties.
Simply put:
In VS 22, I can easily open any class that I'm going to use and most importantly, I can view its parent classes

But VS Code does not provide such an opportunity.

Is there any extension for VS Code that will give me the same functionality as in VS 22?
I tried to find some kind of extension but nothing worked

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to see decompiled C# code in VS Code?
